# Ошибка после обновления до EF6 и попытка даунгрейда безуспешны

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

После обновления до EF 6 упал сайт. После неудачных попыток справиться самому, решил спросить у вас! Ошибка выглядит так:

> Не удалось определить версию хранилища. Необходимо допустимое соединение хранилища или подсказка версии или Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.

```
}
int uid = result.UID;
var newsItem = new News
{
NewsId = result.UID,
Не удалось определить версию хранилища. Необходимо допустимое соединение хранилища или подсказка версии.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlVersionUtils.GetSqlVersion(String versionHint) +8502126
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken) +44
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint) +56
System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken) +27
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

**в web.config-е прописал:**

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

не помогло.

Удалил все что было связано с **_MigrationHistory**

Ругается на файл который находится в **Repository**

Comment: добавте конкретики: какой подход использовался(CodeFirst/DatabaseFirst)?

Comment: Сам проект разделен на множество частей, в разных Areas по разному, но именно тот раздел где ошибка там DataBaseFirst

Comment: обновил ответ. что Бы не предлагать решения которые Вы уже пробовали обновите свой вопрос: укажите что Вы пытались сделать.

Comment: dbml - это LinqToSql. можете попробовать выполнить [данные](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/08/13/linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-conversion-template.aspx) рекомендации?! после них те которые я писал Вам ранее

Comment: @bald56rus, мне кажется что дело не в dbml файле. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в самом коде, в директориях, мне кажется он пути не может определить

Comment: @Bald56rus, Exeption дает такую вот ошибку  "Поставщик не возвратил экземпляр ProviderManifest." Исключение типа "System.Data.DataException" возникло в EntityFramework.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя.

Comment: Отвечаю на оставленную отметку для модератора. Если хотите отредактировать свой вопрос, используйте кнопку [edit]. Если с этим возникли проблемы, тогда пожалуйста уточните их в ответном комментарии ( начните его с "@NickVolynkin", тогда мне придет уведомление).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать сделать следующее:

> 1. Right click over file .edmx
> 2. Open with..
> 3. Editor XML
> 4. Change `ProviderManifestToken="XXXX"` with `2008`

было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25205771) или же советуют стандартно попробовать переустановить Entity Framework.

**UPD**
Данные [рекомендации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) пробовали выполнять?!

Comment: Пытался, но там нет edmx файла, то есть данные связаны через .dbml! Удалил EF 6, переустановил 5(и так несколько раз). Но ошибка не исчезла. Спасибо

Comment: подскажите с какой версии Вы пытаетесь обновится?!

Comment: с 5-ой версии пытался.

Comment: нет, сказать честно не пытался, но я ведь уже переустановил 5-ую версию в надежде все вернуть как раньше было.

Comment: я думаю такой фокус уже не пройдет. как я уже писал выше, напишите что Вы пытались сделать. я надеюсь **backup** проекта Вы предварительно сделали?!