# Подключение к MySql asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Не могу подключиться к базе (локальной). Ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.
Методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)" не удалось получить доступ к методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()".
Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. 

Сведения об исключении: System.MethodAccessException: Методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)" не удалось получить доступ к методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()".
```

Трассировка стека:

```
[MethodAccessException: Методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)" не удалось получить доступ к методу "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()".]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +44
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +87

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +271
   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +43
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +627
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +375
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   WebApplication2.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\shebanits.vitaliy\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\HomeController.cs:24
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748665
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Я так понимаю, что не удается подключиться к базе, но не пойму в чем ошибка, подскажите. Вот код...

web.config

```
 <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" /> 
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;Password=Accessdeniedroma2005;database=musicportal;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Модель с контекстом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
    }

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext() : base("conn")
        {  }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

и часть контроллера:

```
private UsersContext dbUsers = new UsersContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost; Database = musicportal; User ID = root; Password = Accessdeniedroma2005;SslMode=none";
            //using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            //{
            //    cn.Open();
            //    Response.Write("Подключился!");
            //}

            return View(dbUsers.Users.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Публикуйте текст ошибки в **текстовом** виде. Невозможно индексировать и искать когда опубликовано в картинке.

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451832/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-ef6-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: Не, не помола ссылка. Я дополнил вопрос, может будут какие - либо соображения?

Comment: Вот моё решение посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736313/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-ef-getdbprovidermanifesttoken-mysql-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: MySql написан криво (эта версия) попробуйте написать `"conn"` и `"server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;Password=Accessdeniedroma2005;database=musicportal;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true" ` т.е. ваш коннект, и одну из строк закоментировать, если есть ошибка - другую закоментировать. Если это поможет - то возможно и моё решение поможет.

Comment: Стек гляньте, там одна функция не видит другой..такое чувство что они не совместимы..есть какие либо соображения? P.s. при отделке пишет что соединение установленном, но потом прибывание с обеих сторон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался сам. Оказалось при откате версии библиотеки, в конфиге версия не откатывается. Пришлось меня вручную.